# Accessibility of an anchor tag with an icon inside with aria hiden = true

Tags: html, accessibility

I need to use a font awesome icon inside an anchor element. The anchor element does not contain anything rather than the icon.

Ex:

```
<a href="#" aria-label="List">
    <i className="fa fa-list-ul"
        title="List View"
        aria-hidden="true"
        title="List View">
    </i>
</a>
```

What I want to know is is it wrong to put **aria-hidden="true"** to the icon since there is no other text or content inside the anchor tag(In this case  tag becomes informational so I think it is ok to use **aria-hidden="false"** here).

Is there any rules related to this so we all can follow ?

Comment: _"The anchor element does not contain anything rather than the icon."_ - then change that, if you want to do it properly. https://www.24a11y.com/2017/providing-alternate-content-screen-reader-users/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things to consider:

1. people not using assistive technologies (=not relying on ARIA)

   What alternative text will have people not using assistive technologies? A `title` attribute should be added to the `a[href]` tag.

   This will help for instance, people with cognitive deficience, people with low vision, people with bad computer knowledge to understand the meaning of the icon. If you can show the tooltip on keyboard focus, it would also be nice.
2. people using assistive technologies

   [The Fourth rule of ARIA says:](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#4thrule)

   > Do not use role="presentation" or aria-hidden="true" on a visible focusable element

   Perfect here, only the `a[href]` is focusable. This does not prevent you from adding the `aria-hidden` attribute on the `i` element as long as you keep an `aria-label` for valid alternative for assistive technologies.